# How do I get rid of the "semantic analysis" while building an apk in react native (expo)?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have been trying to build an android apk as described in https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/ but I come across this error: [image: problem]

I see some other posts in stackoverflow but it is catered towards flutter or reactnative without expo where they say to change the DistributionUrl or go to android directory and all but I have none of those (I only have a node_modules folder). I tried with Chatgpt but it's not been very helpful. I have cleared all the cache, made all the packages compatible to each other (npx expo install --fix) but nothing seems to work. I tried it on both the server `eas build -p android --profile preview` and my local computer `eas build --platform android --local` and both of them give the same error.

Please help me. Thanks